# Reasons for exempt software engineer to be assigned a 35-hour work week?

Tags: salary, united-states, employees, exempt

I received my first paycheck from my current employer and it stays that I only worked 70 hours in a 2 week period and when I asked HR they stated that I am a 35 hour a week [exempt employee](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/exempt-and-a-non-exempt-employee-2061988):

> Certain types of employees, often classified as exempt employees, are not entitled to overtime pay as guaranteed by the Fair Labor Standards Act (FLSA).

Apparently, the salary is the exact same and the rate is simply higher when calculated.  I am curious as to why my employer would label me as a 35-hour workweek employee that is exempt which essentially means I work the same amount of hours but on paper, I am labeled at only 35 and also the pay is the exact same.  **Is there a benefit for them or for the employee?**

**United States**

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @GrandmasterB United States

Comment: I asked HR and they don't have a good reason at least those that responded.

Comment: How many hours are you expecting/did you work?

Comment: I've been doing 40 hours but after I saw the response for HR that my expected is only 7 hours a day and I can be asked to work as many as required since I am exempt. From now on I'll simply log off earlier but I am simply worried that there might be some legal implications or some other tax benefit/reason that they set me to a 35 hour a week employee.

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica

**Is there a benefit for them or for the employee?**

Comment: could you add your state?

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica Sure I can, do you happen to know of any benefits to an employer to have an employee be salaried yet only work 35 hours a week vs. 40?  In any state in the United States?

Comment: @Rami it seems to be a method for improving work life balance - as an exempt employees you are meant to do on average 35 hours a week instead of 40. I think you many not be clear on what being salaried vs hourly paid means.

Comment: @Neuromancer I am very well aware of what the differences are but in my paycheck calculation it simply stated hourly rate * number of hours worked and the number of hours was 70 even though I entered 80.  The hourly rate * the hours does equal my salary because they simply increased the hourly rate vs. if they did the calculation with 40 hours.  **Now my question is why would they deviate from the standard 40 hours a week and also without even telling me, is there some sort of alterior motive for them? do they get a tax break by having x amount of salaried employees under 40 hours a week?**

Comment: i tried to look into that Q and it seems more and more as as https://law.stackexchange.com/ question

Comment: 35 hours a week is 9-5 with a one hour unpaid lunch break built into the salary. What's the issue?

Comment: ok, I guess there isn't an issue then, who knows why they did it is the answer.

Comment: Were you told it was a 40-hour week?

Comment: Not explicitly unless if it was in one of the documents I signed and didn't read through. That's why I asked here otherwise I would have asked when I received the offer. Also I've already asked some people in HR and so far they've said they don't know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

35 Hours a week is 9-5 with a one hour unpaid lunch break (that has been built into the salary).

The company will probably require you to work unpaid overtime every now and then, but this is a way of signalling that they trust you to be responsible with your hours, and sensible with the breaks you take.

It's a good thing, no need to be suspicious of it.

Comment: Yeah, it's a positive thing

Answer (score -2):

Does it matter how many hours you are paid for?

There are two things that matter. Your salary, and the hours that you actually work.

You worked on average 40 hours a week. Is your salary good / Okish / bad for 40 hours of work at the quality of work that you are doing? That's what you have to decide. If it's not enough, then you can discuss it with whoever is reponsible for your salary and/or your work hours, and you can look for a job elsewhere with fewer hours and better salary.

If in the future your company asks you to work more (say 60 hours a week),  you have to decide again whether the salary is enough or the hours are too much. You are supposed to work more hours if it is required for the company. The company not hiring enough people for the work is *not* a reason to work overtime. The company not organising work properly is *not* a good reason to work overtime. A sales person signing stupid deals is *not* a good reason to work overtime.